# Why is my Heapify That looks down replacing a value with 0 (and maybe other issues)

Tags: c, heap

I'm trying to make a heap. It works to insert, and to check if the value above it fulfils the heap property, but not to check if the value below it fulfils the heap property. For some reason the value of 65 is being replaced with its "left child" (outside the array) which is 0. I have no idea why this is happening. I've been trying to debug this for about an hour now. It might also have some other issues I'm not aware of. The peopole here seem to be able to debug stuff a lot better than me so maybe someone can tell me what the issue is? I have no idea where it's even swapping the value. I probably need to get better at debugging.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SIZE 7

int heap[SIZE];
int fullness = 0;

int getParent(int element){
    //gets the parent of a given index in the heap array
    element -= 2;
    float toDivide = (float)element;
    toDivide /= 2;
    toDivide = ceil(toDivide);
    element = (int)toDivide;

    return element;
}

int getChild1(int element){
    //gets the left child of a given element in the heap list
    element *= 2;
    element += 1;
    return element;
}

int getChild2(int element){
    //gets the right child of a given element in the heap list
    element *= 2;
    element += 2;
    return element;
}

void swapWithChild1(int element){
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < fullness; i++){
        //prints out the elements in the heap after min heapify
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("swapping: %d (left child): %d", heap[element], heap[getChild1(element)]);
    //swaps the chosen element in the heap with its left child
    int child1 = getChild1(element);
    int temp = heap[child1];
    heap[child1] = heap[element];
    heap[element] = temp;
}

void swapWithChild2(int element){
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < fullness; i++){
        //prints out the elements in the heap after min heapify
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //swaps the chosen element in the heap with its right child
    int child2 = getChild2(element);
    int temp = heap[child2];
    heap[child2] = heap[element];
    heap[element] = temp;
}



void minHeapifyLookUp(int element){
    //restores the min heap property of the heap
    if(element == 0){
        return;
    }
    if(heap[element] < heap[getParent(element)]){
        //if the current element in the heap is less than its parent, swap them
        int temp = heap[element];
        heap[element] = heap[getParent(element)];
        heap[getParent(element)] = temp;
        minHeapifyLookUp(getParent(element));
    }
}

void child1AndChild2Heapify(int element){
    //if the left and right child both exist within the list
    bool leftChildLess = false;
    bool rightChildLess = false;
    if(heap[element] > heap[getChild1(element)]){
        //if the left child of the element is less than the element, set bool equal to true
        leftChildLess = true;
    }
    if(heap[element] > heap[getChild2(element)]){
       //if the right child of the element is less than the element, set bool equal to true
        rightChildLess = true;
    }
    if(leftChildLess && rightChildLess){
        if(heap[getChild1(element)] < heap[getChild2(element)]){
            printf("left child is less");
            //if the left child is less than the right child
            swapWithChild1(element);
        }
        else{
            //if the right child is less than or equal to the left child
            swapWithChild2(element);
        }
    }
    else if(leftChildLess){
        swapWithChild1(element);
    }
    else if(rightChildLess){
        swapWithChild2(element);
    }
}

void child1Heapify(int element){
    //if only the left child exists in the heap
    if(heap[element] > heap[getChild1(element)]){
        swapWithChild1(element);
    }
}

void insertToHeap(int insert){
    //inserts an element into the heap and incraments the fullenss varaible
    heap[fullness] = insert;
    fullness++;
    minHeapifyLookUp(fullness-1);
}

void heapifyLookDown(int element){
    //recurusivly checks going down if the heap fufils the min heap property
    printf("element: %d\n", element);
    bool child1Out = false;
    bool child2Out = false;
    if(getChild1(element) > fullness){
        //if the left child is outside the heap
        printf("greater than fullness: %d\n", heap[element]);
        child1Out = true;
        child2Out = true;
    }
    else if(getChild2(element) > fullness){
        //if the right child is outside the heap
        child2Out = true;
    }
    if(!child1Out && !child2Out){
        //if the left and right child are both within the heap
        child1AndChild2Heapify(element);
        //recusivly goes down the heap
        heapifyLookDown(getChild1(element));
        heapifyLookDown(getChild2(element));
    }
    else if(child1Out == false && child2Out){
        //if the right child is outisde the heap but the left child is not
        printf("\nchild 1 is not out and child 2 is out: %d\n", heap[element]);
        child1Heapify(element);
        heapifyLookDown(getChild1(element));
    }

}

void deleteNode( ){


}

int main()
{
    int numList[SIZE] = {400,-1,3,63,12,5,100};
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        //inserts the elements in numList into the heap
        heap[i] = numList[i];
        fullness++;
    }
    heapifyLookDown(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < fullness; i++){
        //prints out the elements in the heap after min heapify
        printf("%d ", heap[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, provide a [mre]. That includes a program that compiles without warning or error. The source code in the question gets a warning or error because `<stdio.h>` is not included. It also includes a copy of the observed output and the expected output. Your program prints various things, and readers should not have to interpret it. You should show what output the program currently actually prints (because it may be different for other people, if there is undefined behavior in the program, or possibly due to other reasons) and you should show the desired output, so we can see where they differ.

Comment: There is no need for floating-point in `getParent`. It can be just `return (element-1)/2;`.

Comment: Your recursive algorithm `heapifyLookDown` will not lead to a valid heap in general. Where did you get it from? Why not implement a proven algorithm?